# Java TTS bot sounds robotic how to make it sounds more like a human?

Tags: java, bots, text-to-speech, voice, freetts

I want to create a TTS bot in java and i using FreeTTS software to this and its sounds like a translator bot is there any option to change a voice speaker to kinda human voice or it is other software to this?

I use kevin voice maybe in FreeTTS is any other voice that sounds less robotic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/).

There are several providers, such as:

- [Google](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml)
- [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html)
- [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup-pronunciation)
- [IBM](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/text-to-speech?topic=text-to-speech-elements)